# Pydev autogen DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable?

Tags: python, django, eclipse, pydev, django-settings

I am using Eclipse 3.7.2 and Pydev 2.6 to develop Django program.
When I upgrade my Django from 1.3 to 1.4.1,
I find a question about "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" environment variable.
When I run manage.py in console, "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" is None first, and via

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "test.settings")
```

will get value correctly.

But when I run code in PyDev, the environment is be set "folder_name.settings" before program.
Even if in non Django program. And I can't find any way to change the value.

How can I set the value outside my program?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The appropriate value for `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` can be set through the Eclipse UI:

Right click on the project folder in the explorer window

Select `Properties`

Select the `PyDev - Django` properties page. You will see a place to enter the correct setting.  If this is blank, PyDev appears to choose a "reasonable" default.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the path structure has changed between Django 1.3 and Django 1.4 so you may simply need to adjust the value of `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` rather than reconfiguring the project entirely. However, if `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` has no value then you need to set it.

You can do:

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=folder_name.settings
```

before running your Django commands (e.g., `runserver`). If you're using `mod_wsgi` then you need to add:

```
import os

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'
```

For more information, see the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#the-django-admin-py-utility) regarding Django settings.